# How do I display a random field in a database table using PHP

Tags: mysql

```
$DBConnect = mysql_connect("host","user"," password");
$dbname = mysql_select_db("databse_name");
$SQLString = "SELECT Proverb FROM randomproverb ORDER BY RANDOM()LIMIT 1";
$QueryResult = mysql_query($SQLString,$DBConnect);
$Row = mysql_fetch_row($QueryResult);
echo $Row;
```

This is my code so far I can not get it to display the field I want in my database table. The most I can do is get the query string it's self to display.

Comment: Generally a good idea not to show your password on one of the most visited coding FAQ website.

Answer (score 1):

As the `mysql_fetch_row` return an `array`, you can't `echo` it.

Change it to this.

```
echo $Row[0];
```